# How to append a string column to array string column in Scala Spark without using UDF?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a table which has a column containing array like this -

```
Student_ID | Subject_List        | New_Subject
1          | [Mat, Phy, Eng]     | Chem
```

I want to append the new subject into the subject list and get the new list.

Creating the dataframe -

```
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, Array("Mat", "Phy", "Eng"), "Chem"))).toDF("Student_ID","Subject_List","New_Subject")
```

I have tried this with UDF as follows -

```
def append_list = (arr: Seq[String], s: String) => {
    arr :+ s
  }

val append_list_UDF = udf(append_list)

val df_new = df.withColumn("New_List", append_list_UDF($"Subject_List",$"New_Subject"))
```

With UDF, I get the required output

```
Student_ID | Subject_List        | New_Subject | New_List
1          | [Mat, Phy, Eng]     | Chem        | [Mat, Phy, Eng, Chem]
```

Can we do it without udf ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Spark 2.4 or later a combination of `array` and `concat` should do the trick,

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{array, concat}
import org.apache.spark.sql.Column

def append(arr: Column, col: Column) = concat(arr, array(col))

df.withColumn("New_List", append($"Subject_List",$"New_Subject")).show
```

```
+----------+---------------+-----------+--------------------+                   
|Student_ID|   Subject_List|New_Subject|            New_List|
+----------+---------------+-----------+--------------------+
|         1|[Mat, Phy, Eng]|       Chem|[Mat, Phy, Eng, C...|
+----------+---------------+-----------+--------------------+
```

but I wouldn't expect serious performance gains here.

Comment: But, you used udf right, my question was that can we do it without udf ?

Comment: No UDFs are defined here. `append` is just an alias, you can do without it: `df.withColumn("New_List", concat($"Subject_List", array($"New_Subject")))`

Comment: @sachav I tried your method but it gives this error - 
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'concat(Subject_List, array(New_Subject))' due to data type mismatch: input to function concat should have StringType or BinaryType, but it's [array<string>, array<string>];

Comment: @GouherDanish It means you're using outdated Spark version (2.3 or earlier). In such case udf is the only option.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I am using earlier spark version. Thanks for your solution, will keep this in mind. I will approve it.

Answer (score -1):

```
 val df = Seq((1, Array("Mat", "Phy", "Eng"), "Chem"),
  (2, Array("Hindi", "Bio", "Eng"), "IoT"),
  (3, Array("Python", "R", "scala"), "C")).toDF("Student_ID","Subject_List","New_Subject")
df.show(false)
val final_df = df.withColumn("exploded", explode($"Subject_List")).select($"Student_ID",$"exploded")
  .union(df.select($"Student_ID",$"New_Subject"))
  .groupBy($"Student_ID").agg(collect_list($"exploded") as "Your_New_List").show(false)
[enter code here][1]
```